# HP ProLiant ML350 G6 driver problems

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, drivers, windows-sbs-2011

We have fresh installed SBS 2011 standard on ML 350 G6 and I ended up with two driver problems
- IPMI interface
- Base system device

We cannot find drivers for them, and I don't know what are those devices.

I would appreciate if someone could help and explain what are those devices and how to find drivers for them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the [HP drivers and software page](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3884316&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D3884316%257CprodSeriesId%253D3884315%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D4108%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) for your operating system, SBS 2011. It is available [here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3884316&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D3884316%257CprodSeriesId%253D3884315%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D4108%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

You have two options for downloading the driver/support pack for the system. One is a [1GB bootable DVD image](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884316&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D3884315%257CprodNameId%253D3884316%257CswEnvOID%253D4108%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-7a8fd7561fb340388b2109cbed%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) download that will provide firmware updates and driver installation for the OS. The other is just the [relevant driver pack](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884316&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D3884315%257CprodNameId%253D3884316%257CswEnvOID%253D4108%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-79b1f86e0dc945c5bc2359f08a%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). Follow the instructions for either download and the installers will configure everything necessary for your system.

Answer (score 4):

HP have the drivers you're looking for. I googled: ["hp ml350 g6 ipmi driver windows"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hp%20ml350%20g6%20ipmi%20driver%20windows)

[Top Link](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3884316&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884315&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005), then head down to "**Driver - Lights-Out Management**" and download the drivers from there.

You should probably install all the relevant drivers for the hardware you've got.  You should know which hardware you've got, you must have ordered it at some point ;)

I suspect that SBS2011 is really just a wrapper around Server 2008R2, so any drivers for that should work too.

Comment: Correct. SBS is pretty much a wrapper. minus a few tweeks.

Comment: There are always driver issues with devices that are not HDD, video card etc. Base system device is .... what? Whatever I have ordered, it has nothing to do with base system device :). It could be a part, or functionality of a device, but not a device itself. Nevermind, how did you relate Driver - Lights-Out Management with my issue?

Comment: Btw, installation error after downloading and installing driver you suggested was "this software is not supported by this OS". Basically I would not ask questions on how to download a single driver, if this is not a more difficult problem

Comment: IPMI stands for Intelligent Platform Management Interface. HP call it Lights-Out Management. It's just HP Experience.

Comment: I'd be tempted to track down a system that it can install on, and extract the archive, grab a CAB file extractor perhaps, grab the .inf files and the .dlls, etc, then drop them onto the target system. Or just not bother.

Comment: Great, I'll do that. What about base system service? What is that?

Comment: I googled. I got this. Looks like it's a specialised frobnosticator.  Install the drivers. http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Ml350-G4P-quot-Base-System-Device-quot/td-p/4253989